# How to convert json using gson to interface type, but still have possibility to use other classes in RoomDatabase

Tags: android, interface, gson, android-room

I get this error:

> Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface com.jimmy.common.ItemWrapper. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

I have a `List<ItemWrapper>` which may be `Dog`,`Cat` or `Snake` class. I need to convert from json to `List<ItemWrapper>` and then in other classes to convert `ItemWrapper` to `Dog`, `Cat` or `Snake`

I tried to find some examples of InstanceCreater, but could understand nothing.

My interface and `ItemWrapperConverter`:

```
public interface ItemWrapper{
  int getViewType();
  int getId();
  void setId(int id);

  // делать их пустыми для всех кроме тех кому они нужны
  void setName(String n);
  void setDescription(String d);
  void setColor(String c);
  void changeNote(int i, String k, String p, long l);
  void changeNote(String k, String p, long l);
  void addNote(Note n);
  void deleteNote(int i);
}

public class ItemWrapperConverter {
@TypeConverter
public String fromItemWrapper(List<ItemWrapper> itemWrappers) {
    if (itemWrappers == null) {
        return (null);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<ItemWrapper>>() {
    }.getType();
    String json = gson.toJson(itemWrappers, type);
    return json;
  }

@TypeConverter
public List<ItemWrapper> toItemWrapper(String ItemWrapperString) {
    if (ItemWrapperString == null) {
        return (null);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<ItemWrapper>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<ItemWrapper> itemWrappers = gson.fromJson(ItemWrapperString, type);
    return itemWrappers;
 }
}
```

I have a `List<ItemWrapper>` which may be `Dog`,`Cat` or `Snake` class. I need to convert from json to `List<ItemWrapper>` and then in other classes to convert `ItemWrapper` to `Dog`, `Cat` or `Snake`

Comment: You need to create custom Type Adapter. Follow this tutorial.http://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Valgaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6009482/valgaal)

follow this [tutorial](http://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html) but instead of T use Object. If u have problems, so delete for example a `serialize()` method and generate the implementation. In my situation I had to change `T` with `Object`